# how to select particular record from a php array

Tags: php

I have an multi dimensional array:

```
$array=array(
[0]=>array([0]=>"100",
           [1]=>"snd",
           [2]=>array(['id']="1",['name']=>"xperia")

),
[1]=>array([0]=>"100",
           [1]=>"snd",
           [2]=>array(['id']="2",['name']=>"xperia")
),

[2]=>array([0]=>"100",
           [1]=>"fkt",
           [2]=>array(['id']="3",['name']=>"xperia")
),
[3]=>array([0]=>"100",
           [1]=>"fkt",
           [2]=>array(['id']="4",['name']=>"xperia")
),
[4]=>array([0]=>"90",
           [1]=>"snd",
           [2]=>array(['id']="5",['name']=>"xperia")
),
[5]=>array([0]=>"90",
           [1]=>"fkt",
           [2]=>array(['id']="6",['name']=>"xperia")
)
);
```

Example what array contains:

```
$array[0][0]=percentage
$array[0][1]=merchant
$array[0][2]=product info
```

i want to display any merchant once whose percentage is between 80-100.
Even if two merchant has 100% match still i want to display it once.

i have used following logic and code:

```
foreach($array as $final_array)
{
if($final_array[0]>=90)
{
echo $final_array[0];
echo $final_array[2]['id'];
echo $final_array[2]['name'];
}
}
```

how can i avoid same merchant information which is displaying double. i have tried array_unique function as well but its showing me first product only.

Comment: in your code you check only `$array[0]`, not every array elements. you need change it to `$final_array`, and [0]-elements has a string with percent sign, but you compare digits.

Comment: Comparing the number `90` to the string `"90%"` is a pretty risky thing like that (`$array[0]>=90`). You compare a number with a string and blindly trust that the automagical conversion will turn `"90%"` into `90`...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems. I guess it needs to be like that:

```
foreach ($array as $final_array)
{
    if ($final_array[0]>=80) {
        echo $final_array[0];
        echo $final_array[2][0];
        echo $final_array[2][1];
    }
}
```

and if you need to avoid duplicates something like this:

```
$merchants = array();
foreach ($array as $final_array)
{
    $merchant = $final_array[1];
    if ( ($final_array[0]>=80) && !in_array($merchant, $merchants) ) {
        $merchants[] = $merchant;
        echo $final_array[0];
        echo $final_array[2][0];
        echo $final_array[2][1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most elegant to filter an array is to use the power of php's array functions combined with a callback:

```
<?php

$input = [
    ["100%", "snd", ['id' =>1, 'name'=>"xperia"]],
    ["100%", "snd", ['id' =>2, 'name'=>"xperia"]],
    [ "90%", "fkt", ['id' =>3, 'name'=>"xperia"]],
    [ "80%", "fkt", ['id' =>4, 'name'=>"xperia"]],
    [ "70%", "snd", ['id' =>5, 'name'=>"xperia"]],
    [ "60%", "fkt", ['id' =>6, 'name'=>"xperia"]],
];

print_r(array_filter($input, function($val){
    return ((int)$val[0] >= 80);
}));
```

*Note: I modified your input values to demonstrate the filter application.*

---

But as written above in the comments: Comparing the number 90 to the string "90%" is a pretty risky thing like that ($array[0]>=90). You compare a number with a string and blindly trust that the automagical conversion will turn "90%" into 90. Maybe you want to invest into some regex number extraction here, *unless* you are 100% certain that those strings always will have exactly that format...

Answer (score 0):

You can create another array to store shown merchants names and check whether current merchant was shown:

```
$shownMerchants = array();

foreach($array as $final_array)
{
    if($final_array[0]>=80 && !in_array($final_array[1], $shownMerchants))
    {
        echo $final_array[0];
        echo $final_array[2][0];
        echo $final_array[2][1];
        $shownMerchants[] = $final_array[1];
    }
}
```

Also, as @arkascha said, it would be better to store the percentage as integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayInput =array(
    0=>array(0=>"100",
               1=>"snd",
               2=>array('id'=>"1",'name'=>"xperia")

    ),
    1=>array(0=>"100",
               1=>"snd",
               2=>array('id'=>"2",'name'=>"xperia")
    ),

    2=>array(0=>"100",
               1=>"fkt",
               2=>array('id'=>"3",'name'=>"xperia")
    ),
    3=>array(0=>"100",
               1=>"fkt",
              2=>array('id'=>"4",'name'=>"xperia")
    ),
    4=>array(0=>"90",
               1=>"snd",
               2=>array('id'=>"5",'name'=>"xperia")
    ),
    5=>array(0=>"90",
               1=>"fkt",
               2=>array('id'=>"6",'name'=>"xperia")
    )
);  

$Merchants = array();

foreach($arrayInput as $key => $val)
{
    $m_name = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar[1].'-'.$ar[0];}, $Merchants); ///get all the merchant name and percentage from $Merchants new array

    if($val[0] >= 80  && !in_array($val[1].'-'.$val[0],$m_name)) /// if % greater than 80 and same merchant with same % not exists than push into array
    {
        $Merchants[] = $val;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($Merchants);
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => snd
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => xperia
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => fkt
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => xperia
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90
            [1] => snd
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => xperia
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90
            [1] => fkt
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => xperia
                )

        )

)
```

***LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/576944)***